# Make radio buttons mutually exclusive when not contained in the same form element?

Tags: forms, web-standards

I'm making a calendar where each day has a radio button that allows you to select it. I want users to only be able to select one day. The issue I'm having is I've made the calendar as a table so each `<td>` has the following:

```html
<td>
  <form>
    Mon 18
    <input type="radio" name="day" value="mon18" />
  </form>
</td>
```

So as all the radio buttons aren't contained in one form element, the normal behaviour that makes the selection mutually exclusive isn't occurring. If I create 1 form element around all my mark up then the table will be contained in it, would this be semantically correct?

Is there a semantically correct solution to my problem? I guess I could do it with javascript and server side validation.

Comment: This may be obvious to you, but you can only do this with javascript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is perfectly semantically correct to have the form enclosing your table, that's actually the only sensible way to build your radiobutton-based calendar with mutually exclusive selection!

The following [code](http://jsfiddle.net/5zxaz/) does validate:

```html
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" name="day" value="1"></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="day" value="2"></td>
            ...
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: What makes your mutually exclusive? Is it the name="day" value?

Comment: Yes exactly, radiobuttons with the same `name` inside the same form are mutually exclusive.